# Cisco AE2500 wireless adapter not recognized after reboot

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, windows

I have used a lot of threads in here to make it work, but since the internal wifi is working, my AE2500 gets the name wlan1 instead of wlan0, which means (as i understand it) that it will only work until i reboot for the first time since installation.

I have been in /ect/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and edited the names in there before the reboot, hoping that it would work this time (I have reinstalled ubuntu too many times today), but it didnt help.

I have mostly been folowing the links in this thread to install the driver:

http://www.grailbox.com/2012/05/installing-cisco-linksys-ae2500-wireless-adapter-in-linux/

hope there is someone who can help me make my wireless adapter work!

Comment: Does it come to life if you simply do: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`?

Comment: no, but somehow i fixed it. It worked when i turned my laptop on this morning.